# C Code - Using a string from an array to pass it as an argument for a shell script

Tags: c

I've been trying to create a simple C code to send a password as argument for a shell script, I need to prevent someone from running a 'strings' command and get my PASSWORD easily. Yes, know it's not totally safe but at least will prevent for any dummie from getting this password easily.
Below you can see my code, but it's complaining about the array :(
I don't know how can I pass the entire content of the array as an argument to the shellscript.sh

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
  char array[] = {'P', 'A', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'D'}; 
  char cmd[1024] = {0};
  char cmd2[1024] = {0};
  char *base = "bash shellscript.sh ";
  sprintf(cmd, "%s", base);
  sprintf(cmd2, "%s %s", cmd, array[]); 

  system(cmd2);
}
```

Comment: `char array[]={'a', 'b', 'c', '\0'}` is fully equivalent to `char array[]="abc"` (note the terminating `\0` though, that you have omitted). So it really won't help to hide it from `strings`.

Comment: `sprintf(cmd, "%s", base)` otherwise known as `strcpy(cmd, base)`.

Comment: You urgently need to read up on `strcat()`.

Comment: Anyway, I don't really see what you are trying to protect here. If I want to get the password from your program, I will simply replace the `shellscript.sh` with another one that it printing it out.

Comment: @tadman `strcat` is harder to use correctly than `snprintf`

Comment: it's not complaining about the array - it's complaining about your attempt to select an array element but omitting the element number (which is a syntax error)

Comment: I was able to fix the code, now it's complaining about special characters in the password string. Does anyone know if it's possible to use characters like @ ! < , in the array ?

Comment: @M.M `strncat()` if you prefer. This approach of creating a bunch of buffers, and printing from one into the next is a huge mess.

Comment: `strncat` is even harder to use correctly  (people often get the length argument wrong).  The original code only needs a single `snprintf`, the `cmd` is redundant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to fix it :)
Here is the new code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
char s3[] = {'P', 'A', 'S', 'S', 'W', 'O', 'R', 'D', '\0'};
char *command = "bash cc.sh";
char *exec;
sprintf(exec,"%s %s",command, s3);
system(exec);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `char s3[] = "PASSWORD";` or `char *s3 = "PASSWORD";` be a bit easier? (such as you did with `command`)?

Comment: Having it spaced out like this is not only bizarre, it is highly error prone.

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour by using uninitialized variable `exec`

Comment: Hi David, if I use as you mentioned, the strings command against the binary file would still outputs the password. That's the intention of the code, hide the password from being easily seen.